# Torsion and Internal Torques of a Stepped Cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque

I am having some difficulty reconciling what my solution manual says and what I calculating. I would appreciate a peer check on the following.

The problem is described by a stepped cylindrical rod rigidly attached to a wall on one side so that the other end is free to rotate. There are three labelled points: Point A at the wall, Point B at the step, and Point C at the free end. There is a positive torque $\textbf{T}$ applied at Point C and a negative torque $\textbf{3T}$ applied at the point B.

An image was requested and I was able to find the following. Please ignore the dimensions and replace $T_2$ with $-\textbf{3T}$ and $T_1$ with $\textbf{T}$.

[image]

I want to find the internal torques $\textbf{T}_{\text{AB}}$ and $\textbf{T}_{\text{BC}}$. The solution manual indicates they are $\textbf{T}_{\text{AB}}$ = $\textbf{3T}$ and $\textbf{T}_{\text{BC}}$ = $\textbf{T}$. I am not getting this though.

My approach is to start with a cut through segment BC and include everything to the right of the cut. Summing the torques (and assuming a negative orientation for internal torque BC):

$-\textbf{T}_{\text{BC}}+\textbf{T} = 0 \Rightarrow \textbf{T}_{\text{BC}}=\textbf{T}$

Okay, that makes sense. Now I will take a cut through segment AB and include everything to the right of the cut. Summing torques (again assuming a negative orientation for internal torque AB) I find:

$-\textbf{T}_{\text{AB}}-\textbf{3T}+\textbf{T} = 0 \Rightarrow \textbf{T}_{\text{AB}} = -\textbf{2T}$

Why am I getting the wrong answer? What have I assumed incorrectly?

Comment: A diagram would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added an image.